# How to set new column equal to subquery PostGreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Full disclosure: I've seen 1 variation of this question for mySQL, and the PostgreSQL answer didn't satisfy me.

I have 2 tables: Reviews & businesses. In the Reviews table, the only 3 relevant columns for the purpose of this question are 'business_id', 'date' (yyyy-mm-dd), and stars (1-5), and the primary key is (review_id). In the businesses table, the relevant columns are 'business_id', 'year', and 'month'.' The 'year' and 'month' columns are there because there is another column in the business table called 'review_count', which represents the number of reviews a business received on each month of each year. Because of this, the composite primary key of this table is (business_id, year, month).

Essentially, **I am trying to create a column in the business table with the average rating (represented by stars) a business received on each month of each year it was open.**

The following query gives me the exact result I want:

```
SELECT round(CAST(AVG(stars) AS NUMERIC), 2)
                                    FROM reviews_for_trending_businesses
                                    WHERE business_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(business_id)
                                                                          FROM trending_businesses_v2)
                                    GROUP BY business_id, EXTRACT("year" FROM reviews_for_trending_businesses.date), EXTRACT('month' FROM reviews_for_trending_businesses.date);
```

This code returns the column and all the correct values that I want to insert into my business table.

However, when I try to actually update the table, I get an error saying more than one row was returned by the subquery used as an expression. This is the code I'm trying to update with:

```
UPDATE trending_businesses_v2
SET avg_monthly_rating = (SELECT round(CAST(AVG(stars) AS NUMERIC), 2)
                                        FROM reviews_for_trending_businesses
                                        WHERE business_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(business_id)
                                                                              FROM trending_businesses_v2)
                                        GROUP BY business_id, EXTRACT("year" FROM reviews_for_trending_businesses.date), EXTRACT('month' FROM reviews_for_trending_businesses.date);
```

I've tried a number of other solutions as well, including using joins, but keep getting a similar error.

**UPDATE: Still No Answer but getting Closer**:
Still can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong here. I also don't understand why I have to groupby 'rtb.date' here if I'm only extracting values from it (returned error if I didn't).

```
UPDATE trending_businesses_v2 tb
    SET avg_monthly_rating = t.val
    FROM (SELECT business_id, EXTRACT("year" FROM rtb.date) AS year, EXTRACT('month' FROM rtb.date) AS month, round(CAST(AVG(stars) AS NUMERIC), 2) as val
          FROM reviews_for_trending_businesses rtb
          WHERE business_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(business_id)

                                FROM trending_businesses_v2
                               )
          GROUP BY business_id, year, month, rtb.date
         ) t
    WHERE t.business_id = tb.business_id AND
          t.year = tb.year AND t.month = tb.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the rows, presumably using a business id and date.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE trending_businesses_v2 tb
    SET avg_monthly_rating = t.val
    FROM (SELECT business_id, date_trunc('month', rtb.date) as yyyymm, round(CAST(AVG(stars) AS NUMERIC), 2) as val
          FROM reviews_for_trending_businesses rtb
          WHERE business_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(business_id)

                                FROM trending_businesses_v2
                               )
          GROUP BY business_id, date_trunc('month', rtb.date)
         ) t
    WHERE t.business_id = tb.business_id AND
          t.yyyymm = tb.?;
```

Comment: hmm that's close but it doesn't seem to be quite working, let me update my code so you can see where I'm at